Power Apps - App Access Checker for modelDriven apps using API calls
I have some dataverse Teams ( O365 groups) in my modelDrivenApp.
I cannot see any member for these Teams until I manually check app Access.
AppAccessChecker
I want to automate this step.
Is there any endpoint that can help me?
I expect something like:
POST:https://api.powerapps.com/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/scopes/admin/environments/{environmentId}/apps/{appId}:CheckAccess

Headers:

Authorization: Bearer token per l'autenticazione
Content-Type: application/json

body:
{
  "principalId": "user-guid",
  "principalType": "User"
}

